# How does a DHCP server know which network interface and subnet the new IP address should be on

Tags: dhcp

I've read that DHCP servers add a column to your iptable in your router. A new dynamically created IP address with a network interface and a subnet mask. Then the IP address is matched with your MAC address and your client becomes part of a network.

How does the DHCP server know which network interface and subnet it should use in which process?

1. DHCPDISCOVER
2. DHCPOFFER
3. DHCREQUEST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've read that the DHCP server adds a column to your iptable in your
> router.

No. DHCP is between a host and the DHCP servers using broadcast, so the DHCP server is on the same network as the host and knows about the network.

There is also DHCP relay, where the relay stands in for the server and talks to the server for the host, telling the server which network to use. The relay must be on the same network as the host because DHCP uses broadcast.

Comment: Yes, but who chooses the interface and the subnet, can the computer forward this to the relay agent or something?

Comment: The network is the one to which the host is connected. A DHCP server on the same network as the host uses that network, or the DHCP relay tells the server the network where the relay is connected. A relay agent or the DHCP server are connected to the network where the host is connected, and that is the network used. The host has no idea if there is a relay or not, it just uses broadcast.

Comment: When I would create a new computer and plug the ethernet cable in, can I choose wich subnet in the interface the computer is connected?

Comment: The network to which it is connected would already be determined by the configuration of the other devices already on the network. If all the devices connected to that network are in the `10.0.0.0/24` network, then that is the network. Choosing a different network for your host makes no sense because it would not communicate with the other devices. The DHCP server or relay will be connected to the network and already addressed on that network.

Comment: When you add a new computer you add it to a fysical interface right? You don't yet add it to a subnet in the interface, so how would it know wich subnet in the fysical interface or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vexea The keyword here is *broadcast domain* which the DHCP server (or relay) and the DHCP client need to share. In its simplest form it's formed by a basic switch but can also be a VLAN. The broadcast domain you connect a client to determines the DHCP server it can send requests to.

Comment: @Vexea, again, the DHCP server or relay on the network to which you physically attach the unconfigured host will already be addressed in a network. That is the network used by DHCP to configure the host.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. So every computer I attach to my ethernet cable right now is connected to the network but doesn't have an actual address? The relay-agent is on the client-side of the router and hears the broadcast in the subnet my computer is physically connected to and then asks my dhcp server for an offer?

Comment: We cannot answer for you particular network unless you provide a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Otherwise, we can only speculate about you network, but guessing and speculation are off-topic here.

Comment: @Vexea, in a word: yes, that's how it works. The DHCP relay adds its own address to the DHCP request, and the server uses that to figure out which network the client is in.